# JavaScript: Boolean of logical expression that includes undefined - Unexpected behaviour

Tags: types, boolean, undefined

MY QUESTION: In the following code, everything makes sense except for the last two lines. I would expect them to log true as they are essentially the same as the previous two lines.

```
let varUndefined;
console.log(Boolean(varUndefined));             //Logs false
console.log(Boolean(0));                        //Logs false
console.log(Boolean(false === false));          //Logs true
console.log(Boolean(false == false));           //Logs true
console.log(Boolean(varUndefined === 0));       //Logs false
console.log(Boolean(varUndefined == 0));        //Logs false
```

CONTEXT: I'm just studying; this is not part of a project. In view of this behaviour, I have made a mental note to avoid the undefined type like the plague - until I understand what is going on here. Thank you kindly for any information.

UPDATE 12 OCT 2022: Digging deeper, I have run the following:
`console.log(Boolean(undefined)); //Logs false`

Imho, this doesn't help to answer the question.

Comment: undefined isn't false, it's undefined.  It's it's own type, and it doesn't coerce to a truthy value, either:  _https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined_

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply, @ChrisStrickland! The thing is, what you have said here seems to contradict a test I just did:
console.log(Boolean(undefined)); //Logs false
So it seems that undefined does have a "truthy value".  :-)

Comment: Hi @ChrisStrickland. I've just read carefully through the Mozilla link you kindly gave me: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined . This is very informative about undefined and I've bookmarked it for future use, but I don't think it answers my question - unless I'm missing something.  :-)

Comment: It's not as helpful as it could be, no.  The reason Boolean(undefined) returns a truthy value (well, not truthy, an actual Boolean) is because you are explicitly converting it to Boolean, see this: _  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/Boolean _ and then google the difference between coercion (implicit) and conversion (explicit) in JS

Comment: for instance, https://idiallo.com/javascript/type-coercion-conversion-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you, @ChrisStrickland. I will look into all those references. You are really kind. In the meantime I believe I have seen my error. I knew that Boolean(varUndefined) is false and Boolean(0) is false and I deduced from that that Boolean(varUndefined === 0) is therefore true. Fundamentally, I was assuming that the Boolean() operation is 'distributive' (in the math sense) over the logical AND operator. But now I see that, of course, it isn't! So.... When the JS engine sees Boolean(A === B), it first does A===B and THEN, AFTER THAT, does Boolean() on the result. That explains it!  (contd...)

Comment: (Contd from above) Just to explain, this is the code that sparked my question. I knew that Boolean(undefined) is false, so I couldn't understand why it logged nothing to the console!  `const superLongArray = [1,67,45,67,8902,34,54,26,76.2,4,3,88,99,200,34,67,42]; let notFound; while (superLongArray.length > 0 && notFound === true) {   if (superLongArray[0] != 42) {     superLongArray.shift();   } else {     console.log("Found 42!");     notFound = false;   } }`
Lol! Sorted now. Clearly, my minimalist aproach doesn't work and I have to declare **and assign** notFound at the beginning!  :-)